# Change weight of CSS file loaded in custom module with #attached?

Tags: theming

Im working on a custom module which loads a CSS file:

```
$content['#attached']['css'] = array(
  path_to_theme() . '/new.css',
);
```

How can I change the weight of the file so that its loaded after the other CSS files? I thought it would be something like this:

```
$content['#attached']['css'] = array(
  path_to_theme() . '/new.css',
  'weight' => 1000,
);
```

Or this:

```
$content['#attached']['css'] = array(
  path_to_theme() . '/new.css',
  '#weight' => 1000,
);
```

Comment: May I ask why would you do that?

Comment: As its a custom module it has some custom styles that I would like loaded after the base styles of my theme. Eg if my theme has a class of button and this module's style has a class of button--large, then I need button--large to be loaded after button.

Comment: it would be much easier to override base styles with ´! important´ I think

Comment: @Benone_ Nope, if you see `!important` in CSS, 99% of the time it means the developer wasn't quite sure what they were doing

Comment: @Clive with proper selector it would not do any unwanted changes

Comment: @Benone_ I'd encourage you to type "css important bad" into Google and read the top 5 or so pages that come up - they should clear up without question why it shouldn't be used, except for the purpose it was actually designed for in the first place (user style sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this:

```
$content['#attached']['css'] = array(
  array(
    'data' => path_to_theme() . '/new.css',
    'type' => 'file', 
    'weight' => 1000,
  ),
);
```